# Query on Tensor Product of Quaternion Algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

[image]

In this proof of isomorphism of tensor product of quaternion algebras I have two queries:

1) Why does one need to "check $xy=yx$ for all $x\in C$ and $y\in D$?

2) How is the product $CD$ defined?

Thanks! I understand that this topic of quaternion algebras is not mainstream, hope there is an expert here who could help!

Comment: 1) In the definition of the tensor product $C \otimes D$, every element of $C$ commutes with every element of $D$. 2) This just means the subring of $A$ spanned by $C$ and $D$.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know (1). Even Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_algebras) doesn't mention that every element $C$ must commute with $D$!

Comment: It's not that it must. It's that it does. Whatever $C$ and $D$ are, $c\otimes 1$ commutes with $1\otimes d$ in $C\otimes D$ ; it's not a condition, it's a fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof constructs two subalgebras $C$ and $D$ of $A$.

You want to show that $C\otimes D\simeq A$, so you need to give an isomorphism $C\otimes D\to A$. The tensor product of two algebras $X$ and $Y$ has the following universal property : for any algebra $Z$, any two morphisms $f: X\to Z$ and $g: Y\to Z$ such that $f(x)g(y)=g(y)f(x)$ for all $x\in X$, $y\in Y$ extend uniquely to a morphism $X\otimes Y\to Z$.

Here you want to apply this to the inclusions $C\to A$ and $D\to A$, so you have to check that elements of $C$ commute with elements of $D$. One this is done, you have your morphism $C\otimes D\to A$.

By construction, $C$ and $D$ are quaternion algebras, so in particular central simple algebras, so $C\otimes D$ is simple, and this morphism must be injective. Then checking the dimensions, it's bijective and $C\otimes D\simeq A$.

The subspace $CD$ is defined as the subspace spanned by products $cd$ with $c\in C$ and $d\in D$. If $C$ and $D$ commute, then $CD$ is the image of the natural morphism $C\otimes D\to A$.

(PS: I don't know if this topic is "mainstream", but it's certainly not confidential or obscure.)

Comment: Very nice answer to something that puzzled me for weeks.